# Syntax Error - Missing ')'

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I am user69787. I can't seem to register that account. Thank you @PartOfTheOhana. I am now getting syntax error. **Missing ')'**

```
OR(

    AND(
        ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
        OR(
            $UserRole.DeveloperName =="Client_Growth_Manager",
            $UserRole.DeveloperName =="Inside_Sales_Executive",
            $UserRole.DeveloperName =="Business_Development_Associate",
            $UserRole.DeveloperName =="Director_of_Sales",
            $UserRole.DeveloperName =="Senior_Relationship_Manager",
            $Permission.Allowed_to_Change_Account_Owner == FALSE
        )
    )
    ,

    AND(
        ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
        (ISPICKVAL(Industry, "Furniture")),
        (ISPICKVAL(Program__c, "Retail Furniture"),
        $Permission.Specialty_Retail == FALSE

    )


)
```

Comment: I think I got it. Line 19 needed a parenthesis. Testing to see if it works since I can now save it.

Comment: Please use the Contact link at the bottom of the page to ask Stack Exchange support for help merging your two accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update this line

`(ISPICKVAL(Program__c, "Retail Furniture")),` .. you need to close the parenthesis.